# Android Bitmap native API to create android.graphics.Bitmap instance

Tags: android, bitmap, java-native-interface

I'm using native code and I have a buffer of pixels (i.e int* buffer). I want to create a android.util.Bitmap instance from the buffer with a specific width, height.

Currently, I return the buffer to Java and using android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap() to create a Bitmap instance. But it seems to be not efficient and it throws OutOfMemoryException   in my phone (less resources), but work in tablet (more resources).

My question is: How can I create a Bitmap instance in the native way (i.e. create such instance in C and return as a Bitmap in Java using JNI interface)?

Comment: sorry, can you write how do you pass buffer from native code and crate bitmap in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large is the bitmap? if it throws OOM in Java, any attempt to pass it back from C would probably do the same - it will still need to consume Java memory. Consider a bitmap format that takes less space per pixel - say, RGB_565, or ARGB_4444.

Comment: My data contains bitmaps about 3000 x 5000 pixels, I have tried with differences Bitmap.Config, no luck.

Comment: That's pretty big. You're not drawing it whole, are you? Consider somehow cutting it up in C and passing back to Java only the pieces Java needs.

Comment: Indeed, I would display the whom image with zoom/pan capabilities. I tried to scale down (in native code) and it works with the reduction in image quality. Is there any way to convert an image to Bitmap object directly in native code?

Comment: In theory, you can *draw* directly in native code. I'm not sure how though, and you'll probably end up reduplicating a lot of system code. Converting the image to Bitmap in native code - it would still use JVM resources and would be subject to the same Java-based memory constraints. Also, you might want to look up increasing the memory quota for your Java process. It's not like you're exhausting system memory - each Java process has a memory limit of its own.